How can I resolve "Unknown data source" when linking to Crashlytics BigQuery table in Looker?
I have enabled integration to BigQuery in Firebase and am exporting the Analytics and Crashlytics tables. I can view and query the tables in BigQuery studio.
I want to use Looker to make a report for Crashlytics (there is already a template there for this).
When I link to BigQuery, I can see the table, and can see the fields, but when I explore the data or generate the report, I get:

Unknown data source The data source associated with this component
could not be loaded

And then in details:
The data source associated with this component could not be loaded

We were not able to find the data source associated with this
component. This can happen when a data source is deleted.

Linking works fine:

Can then select the data source:

But I just get this error for each component on the report:

I can see the 400 XHR request that results in this error:

For some reasons the Analytics table works OK - it's just the Crashlytics tables that cannot be linked to Looker reports.
I did wonder if it was Geo-location so I added a Replication in BigQuery to europe-west (from default of US) - as I am based in UK and I noticed that the Analytics table was linked to BigQuery as europe-west (whereas it is not possible to set region in Crashlytics linking) - but this did not help.
